# Using descriptive test names in TDD

Tags: oop, tdd

While reading the book [GOOS](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) the author tells us to name long and descriptive names in tests to understand what the object under test does. For example:

`notifiesListenersThatServerIsUnavailableWhenCannotConnectToItsMonitoringPort()`

is better than

`pollsTheServersMonitoringPort()`

but most style guides tells us to follow 80 or 100 column rule. What others have to say on this?

Comment: The test name should describe the scenario under test in as few words as possible. This still leads to verbose test names in many cases, which I don't mind, but I try to strike a balance and not have them too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get away with it for unit tests as you never actually have to call the methods directly. You wouldn't for example want a public API with really long wordy names, but for tests this also forms documentation for fellow developers.
Its a trade off. In this context more descriptive names are much better. Its the pragmatic approach.

Personally with widescreen monitors I would say 120 characters line length as a minimum. 80 is a throwback from terminals.

Comment: Started with 80 column punched cards!

Comment: Accepting the answer as it feels to me that it depends on the personal preferences and team convenience. To me it feels fine.